# Why does my nestled while loop keep repeating?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

It seems I can't get my nestled while loop to stop repeating the output `print('Y/N only accepted answers.')`.  The first while loop I have works as intended, whereas if I enter anything other than Y/y/N/n, it tells me once that Y/N are the only accepted answers, then repeats the question a single time.

```
def initalSequence():
    print('*WELCOME*')
    trueVar1 = True
    while trueVar1:
        response1 = input('Do you like pizza? Y/N: ')
        if response1 == 'Y' or response1 == 'y' or response1 == 'N' or response1 == 'n':
            response2 = input('Are you sure about that? (Y/N): ')
            trueVar1 = False
            trueVar2 = True
            while trueVar2:
                if response2 == 'Y' or response2 == 'y' or response2 == 'N' or response2 == 'n':
                    print(countDown())
                    trueVar2 = False
                    break
                else:
                    print('Y/N only accepted answers.')
                    continue
        else:
            print('Y/N only accepted answers.')
            continue

print(initalSequence())
```

I simply want the nestled while loop to do exactly what the initial while loop is doing.  I could understand utilizing a try and except if I was asking for integers, but I don't know of how I could utilize that with a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Move line `response2 = input('Are you sure about that? (Y/N): ')` inside the nestled while loop.

> I simply want the nestled while loop to do exactly what the initial while loop is doing.

What the outer while loop does.

```
trueVar1 = True
while trueVar1:
    response1 = input('Do you like pizza? Y/N: ')
    if response1 == 'Y' or response1 == 'y' or response1 == 'N' or response1 == 'n':
        trueVar1 = False
        # Do something. Once done, exit loop
    else:
        print('Y/N only accepted answers.')
        continue
```

So, the inner while loop should be

```
trueVar2 = True
while trueVar2:
    response2 = input('Are you sure about that? (Y/N): ')
    if response2 == 'Y' or response2 == 'y' or response2 == 'N' or response2 == 'n':
        trueVar2 = False
        # Do something, once done, exit loop
    else:
        print('Y/N only accepted answers.')
        continue
```

This should work.

> Why does my nestled while loop keep repeating?

Because `response2` input is acquired outside the inner while loop, and if its value is anything different from `Y` or `y` or `N` or `n`, it will cause a infinite loop, very like the example below.

```
while True:
    if False:
        # nothing inside this if will be executed,
    else:
        print('Y/N only accepted answers.')
        continue
```

The solution, simply move `response2 = input('Are you sure about that? (Y/N): ')` inside the nestled while loop.